# How do I get the primary key columns in ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeliveryData](
    [DeliveryId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   ...
CONSTRAINT [PK_DeliveryData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DeliveryId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And code:

```
public void GetPrimaryKeyColumns(SqlConnection conn) {
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from [dbo].[DeliveryData]";
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly);
    DataTable schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
    DataColumn[] columns = schema.PrimaryKey;
    ...
}
```

cmd, reader, and schema all look good, but columns ends up a zero length array. Shouldn't it contain "DeliveryId"?  How can I get the primary column "DeliveryId"?

Thanks for the help!

Blake

Comment: You never open the connection so `cmd.ExecuteReader` should be throwing an exception. I suspect you have a `catch{}` block that hides exceptions

Answer (score 0):

The schema table is not the `DeliveryData` table. You must inspect the schema table where the `IsKey` column is true and then grab the `ColumnName` field. You can then use that find the real column on a regular data table.

> Update

`GetSchemaTable()` returns a data table of metadata information which you can see in the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable(v=vs.110).aspx

You end up with as many rows in the returned DataTable as you would have columns in the query if you were to run the query. Here is a partial screenshot of the schema table I get from a test table in my database. Notice every column is now a row, and the IsKey field will tell you if the column is a key column:
[image]

If you want to use the `PrimaryKey` property on a DataTable do not use `GetSchemaTable()`, just use a `SqlDataAdapter` to fill a regular DataTable.

> Update 2

use `CommandBehavior.KeyInfo` instead of `CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly`

> Using SMO

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
....

Server svr = new Server("Your Server Name");
Database db = svr.Databases["Your Database Name"];
Table tbl = db.Tables["DeliveryData"];
foreach (Column c in tbl.Columns)
{
    bool isAKeyColumn = c.InPrimaryKey

}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I am still lost.  The cmd.CommandText specifies the layout of what is returned.  The reader should be for DeliveryData.  It's not like I am asking for the entire DB schema.  Also, looking for a column with pri set doesn't help with composite primary keys.  Could you be a little more long-winded?  Thanks!

Comment: The link you provided states "Returns a DataTable that describes the column metadata of the SqlDataReader.".  My reader is on the DeliveryData table, so GetSchemaTable on my reader should provide the schema of my reader.  Also, the IsKey field will not work for composite keys.  Can you modify the code I originally provided to work?  Thanks!

Comment: It returns the schema of the result set. Put a break point and use the DataTable Visualizer to look at the table you get. It will look just like mine except different column names. I get the feeling you don't want to  use `GetSchemaTable` at all, I think you misunderstand what it is. However, `IsKey` will be true for all columns that participate in the primary key, so you can still use it if you want.

Comment: I did as you suggest and see what you indicate.  Two problems though.  First, given the table definition I showed you, none of the IsKey fields are true.  Second, I can't use this fopr composite keys because even if I know what columns make it up, I don't know the column order for the index.

Comment: I think you want to use a SqlDataAdapter to fill a DataTable with your command and use the `PrimaryKey` property on that one instead of using a schema table. However, neither method is giving me the primary key of my test table. Seems unreliable. Maybe you should go with using [SQl Management Objects (smo)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162557.aspx) to inspect table metadata.

Comment: Given the fact that the 'schema' variable contains all of the correct columns for my table, I am pretty sure I now know what the problem is.  If you create a table using the structure I show, you'll see that MSSQL does not return the primary key columns.

Comment: While using the correct CommandBehavior makes the API return the IsKey column data, it still doesn't solve the problem in cases of composite keys.

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL doesn't return correct primary key information in all cases using GetSchemaTable.  (Not too surprising.  For example, almost all DB vendors support ODBC better than MS.)  The following query, however, does work:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS as tc
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE as  kcu
    ON kcu.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = tc.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
    AND kcu.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = tc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    AND kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    AND kcu.TABLE_CATALOG = tc.TABLE_CATALOG
    AND kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA = tc.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND kcu.TABLE_NAME = tc.TABLE_NAME
WHERE tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE ='PRIMARY KEY'
    AND tc.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    AND tc.TABLE_NAME = 'DeliveryData'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

Comment: Did you see my update, it does if you use KeyInfo command behavior. Verified it worked, exactly as documented by MS.

Comment: While your update does get me to where you started, it still doesn't work for composite keys.  Also, I bet if I put a separate index on three different columns, each of the three would show as IsKey true.  Doesn't help at all.

Comment: Happy you solved your problem, but it is not the question you asked. Maybe you can add the reasoning so googlers won't land here for the wrong reason.

Comment: I very much appreciate your help.  It kept me going to the solution.  My original question was: "How do I get the primary key columns in ADO.NET?"  The answer is:  "You can't via the ADO.NET schema API.  However, you can use the ANSI 92 standard query I provide with the normal ADO.NET query API."

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete solution:

```
public List<string> GetPrimaryKeyColumns(DbConnection conn, string schema, string table) {
    DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    DbParameter p = cmd.CreateParameter();
    p.ParameterName = "@schema";
    p.Value = schema;
    p.DbType = DbType.String; 
    p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

    p = cmd.CreateParameter();
    p.ParameterName = "@table";
    p.Value = table;
    p.DbType = DbType.String;
    p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT kcu.COLUMN_NAME
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS as tc
                        LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE as  kcu
                            ON kcu.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = tc.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
                               AND kcu.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = tc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
                               AND kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                               -- AND kcu.TABLE_CATALOG = tc.TABLE_CATALOG  doesn't work on MySQL
                               AND kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA = tc.TABLE_SCHEMA
                               AND kcu.TABLE_NAME = tc.TABLE_NAME
                        WHERE tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE ='PRIMARY KEY'
                              AND tc.TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema
                              AND tc.TABLE_NAME = @table
                        ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION";

    DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);

    List<string> res = new List<string>();
    while (reader.Read()) {
        var str = reader[0];
        if (str != System.DBNull.Value)
            res.Add((string) str);
    }
    reader.Dispose();
    cmd.Dispose();
    return res;
}
```